# Upload iOS App to AppStore using port 443

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, application-loader

I am trying to upload our apps from command line using altool. Since our firewall blocks some ports, I want to transfer the files in "DAV" mode using HTTPS on port 443. If I do that manually using ApplicationLoader GUI, I can set a parameter for that. Does anybody know the correct parameters for altool?

The documentation does not mention anything about that.
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Currently I am using the following command (which does not work, because altool can't access the Apple server on the default port):

```
altool --upload-app -f file -u username [-p password]
```

Best regards

Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be unofficial way as of today, we are able to transfer in DAV with setting UserDefaults key `ITunesTransport` for altool like following:

```
defaults write com.apple.itunes.altool ITunesTransport DAV
```

Or, directly append it as altool command line arguments like following:

```
altool --upload-app -f file -u username [-p password] -ITunesTransport DAV
```

It is working with Xcode 10 in our firewall.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, I cannot test this behavior anymore, because we ended up with configuring our firewall to allow communication to the Apple servers. If someone other can confirm this behavior, I would like to accept your answer as correct answer.

Comment: I tested adding `-ITunesTransport DAV` to the cli args for notarizing an app and that does force webdav mode. Thank you so much, Tochiji!
Though I'm curious about how you figured this out. As far as I can tell, your stack overflow answer is the only reference to "altool" and "ITunesTransport" together on the internet :P